# organising y axsis with using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of values from - 1 to 1 which I am plotting using matplotlib on a the y axis

I would like the way axis of my graph to be set up as -1,0,1.

However it appears to be ignoring the fact the number is negative.

I have tried using plt.ticks but unfortuntelty that doesn't get the desired result.

so normally it looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSuu5.png)

if i add plt.yticks(range(-1,1)), it displays as this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8gug.png)

data is ['0.5', '-0.3', '0.0', '0.0', '0.1'] - my data set will be increasing and it is already organised

plt.plot(data,color='b', marker= 'o')

plt.ylim([-1,2])

plt.show()

**Fixed ittttttttttttt, the numbers were a string, so i converted it to a float and it worksssssss** **thank you everyone**

Comment: update:: Its not about limiting the values on the y axis. I just want them to be organise from -1 to 1

Comment: Be informed that `range(-1,1)` means [-1, 0]. For what you want, you need `range(-1,2)`. Also share your code in your question for others to be able to help you

Comment: yea @Bazingaa i realised this afterwards, still unfortunatly doesn't work

Comment: Share your data and code please

Comment: Hi, please see amended post @Bazingaa

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were plotting strings. You need to convert them to floats before plotting. That's the reason you were seeing a strange y-axis with mixed up order of negative, positive, negative numbers

```
data = ['0.5', '-0.3', '0.0', '0.0', '0.1'] 
data = list(map(float, data))

plt.plot(data,color='b', marker= 'o')
plt.yticks(range(-1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: thank youuuu I spotted it too. I have been working on this all day :/

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help :)